# Terraform syntax for putting json as value in a map

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm new to terraform. I have a json object that I need to set as the value in a terraform map so that the resource gets created with the json as the value.

The .tf file looks like this in that section:

```
...

      config_overrides = {
        override_1      = "True"
        override_2      = '{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}' #this is the json object
    }

...
```

However, the terraform lint command `terraform lint -check` is failing on the json object.

```sh
$ terraform fmt -check

Error: Invalid character

  on myterraform.tf line 28, in resource <<resource name>> :
  28:         override_2 = '{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}'

Single quotes are not valid. Use double quotes (") to enclose strings.


Error: Invalid expression

  on myterraform.tf line 28, in resource <<resource name>>:
  28:         override_2 = '{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}'

Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.
```

I have tried many different variations and cant get the linter to accept it. Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Terraform's `jsonencode` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html) so that Terraform itself is responsible for generating the JSON and you only need to worry about the data structure:

```
  override_2 = jsonencode({
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
  })
```

Terraform's object expression syntax happens to be similar to JSON's and so the argument to `jsonencode` here looks a lot like the JSON string it'll convert to, but that is really just a normal Terraform expression and so you can include any [Terraform expression constructs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html) in there. For example:

```
  override_2 = jsonencode({
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": var.any_variable,
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `\` in the value `'` isn't going to work.

```
config_overrides = {
  override_1 = "True"
  override_2 = "{\"key1\":\"val1\",\"key2\":\"val2\"}"
}
```